# Get more then 25 comments from a Video

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-api

### Question

I'm having promblems getting more then the default 25 comments per request in my application. I know I have to set the `max-results` parameter, but whenever I try to set it, the application crashes with a `GDataRequestException` with the information `Execution of request failed`. But the url looks okay:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kpzWVicfdQk?max-results=50`

Used code:

```
string url = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{0}?max-results=50", "kpzWVicfdQk");

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(new YouTubeRequestSettings("GComments","***"));
Video v = request.Retrieve<Video>(new Uri(url));
Feed<Comment> comments = request.GetComments(v);
```

Without `?max-results=50` it works perfectly. I tried setting it to `new Uri(url)` too, but it does not work too.

### Solution

The problem was, that the retrieved feed is a comment feed, but I used a kind of a video Feed. Here is the updated, now working, code:

```
void getComments()
{
    string url = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{0}/comments?max-results={1}&start-index={2}", "kpzWVicfdQk", 50, 1);

    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(new YouTubeRequestSettings("GComments","AIzaSyB5d2gsN2G9xYftU3zFPKDg7kyBlrHni7A"));
    Feed<Comment> comments = request.Get<Comment>(new Uri(url));
}
```

Comment: "Without ?max-results=50 it works perfectly.": In this case the response is not a "Comments Feed" (which is what you want), but a single "Video Entry".

Comment: Ah, i recognize the kind of string. If it is supposed to be a value for a parameter named GComments, then i think it will just be ignored.

Comment: GComments is the name of the Application as set in the API console and this string is the dev key. The key isn't valid anymore, I just forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max-results can be 50.
You have the wrong url for retrieving comments. Add "comments" after the videoId, like in:

```
 http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kpzWVicfdQk/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1
```

Change start-index to advance if you expect more comments.

Or check the response for a rel="next" link, like:

```
<link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kpzWVicfdQk/comments?start-index=51&amp;max-results=50&amp;direction=next&amp;v=2'/>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but do you know, how I have to customize my code to get comments? Because it isn't working with my code right now, I'm getting the same exeption.

Comment: I don't use that code language (c#). But i see the url in the first line is wrong. What does it mean in line 2: new YouTubeRequestSettings("GComments","***"). And why do you mention video in line 3: request.Retrieve<Video>. The url i gave returns a Comments FEED.

Comment: Thank you, It works now, will update my question to show the solution

Answer (score 1):

The `max-results` parameter only applies to feeds for finding multiple videos (i.e. if searching for videos by keyword, or most popular). It limits the number of returned videos. The parameter is not valid when retrieving a single video.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question on how to retrieve more than 25 comments, but the API documentation does not make any mention of a default limit in the retrieved comments?